# Бот уведомление после загрузки файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть следующий код

```
async def handle_docs_photo(message: types.Message):
    try:
        files = await bot.get_file(message.photo[-1].file_id)
        # await message.answer('data/' + str(message.from_user.id) + files.file_path[-12:])
        await bot.download_file_by_id(message.photo[-1].file_id,
                                      'data/' + str(message.from_user.id) + '/' + files.file_path[-12:])
        logger.info('{} {}', message.from_user.username,
                    'data/' + str(message.from_user.first_name) + '/' + files.file_path[-12:])
        await message.answer('Все сохранено', reply_markup=inkb)
    except Exception as e:
        await message.answer(f'{message.text}, {e}')
```

После того как все сохранено он пишет, что все сохранено

```
await message.answer('Все сохранено', reply_markup=inkb)
```

И выдает инлайн клавиатуру, как сделать так чтобы это сообщение выдавалось один раз, после загрузки пачки фотографий.
В данный момент пишет столько раз сколько было отправлено файлов.

Comment: проходиться циклом по списку файлов и их загружать, и по окончанию цикла выдать сообщение

Comment: прогоните все файлы сначала в цикле, а потом выдайте ответ вне цикла. незагрузившиеся файлы можете в логи выкидывать, либо записывать еще куда то.

Comment: Сначала собрать все фото в список, а потом по нему циклом пройтись? Ок, попробуем так.

Comment: Теперь не понятно как собрать все файлы в список? для бота каждый отправленный файл это один апдейт который перехватывает хэндлер. И дальше где ставить цикл для обработки?